# WIX: How to implement a gallery slide show for all the post in a blog

Tags: slideshow, blogs, velo

I'am working on a blog web site. Each blog has an image. I need a slide show that will show all posts (or some posts) with their images as a slideshow.]

Have read WIX help pages and there explanations on how to make a slide show for a single post but not for all the post.

We are thinking about migrating from WP where we have a plugin that after adding a post we can see the image in the slide show. After reading about blogs in WIX I am not sure that this is a good ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the sort of effect you are looking for:

[image: image gallery view of blog posts using wix]

When you are in the Wix Editor you can add different Blog feed layouts using the Add Element button...

[image: How to select a blog feed using Add Element Button in the Wix Editor]

Check out the Blog Articles for more help here:
https://support.wix.com/en/new-wix-blog